# how to pass prior and current value to apex when record changes through process builder?

Tags: apex, process-builder, salesforce-id, field-update

how to pass prior and current value to apex when record changes through process builder?

ex: when the field update occurs like contact last name using process builder.. how to pass the prior and updated value as a parameter to apex method.

any ideas appriciated. thank you

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved using below Class and Process Builder:

```
public class PrintInvocable {

public class MyInvocableVariable {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Id' required=true)
    public Id recId;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Old Value' required=true)
    public String oldVal;

    @InvocableVariable(label='Current Value' required=true)
    public String currVal;
}

@InvocableMethod(label='Old and Current Value' description='Print Old and Current Values')
public static void printOldAndCurrentValues(List<MyInvocableVariable> myInvocableVariableList) {

    for(MyInvocableVariable myInvocableVariable : myInvocableVariableList) {
        system.debug('recId=' + myInvocableVariable.recId + ', oldVal=' + myInvocableVariable.oldVal + ', currVal=' + myInvocableVariable.currVal);            
    }
}
```

}

[image]